# Can a radio share a MAC address with the ethernet interface of an access point?

Tags: ethernet, mac-address, ieee-802.11

I have a situation where I have found the BSSID to have a MAC address congruent to the MAC address of the ethernet interface.

1. Is this possible?
2. Does this happen with all access points?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That shouldn't happen. Each interface should have a unique MAC address.

Actually, each interface's MAC address should be *globally* unique but that isn't really the case any more. However, the vendor needs to take care that an address collision is extremely unlikely (re-use addresses only between different geographic regions).

Using the same MAC address in *different networks* (perspective of wired nodes vs perspective of wireless nodes) should work though. I don't see a direct problem in your case. MAC addresses need to be unique for different L3 interfaces. A WAP in bridge mode works on L2 and only really requires a MAC address for its SSID and for its management interface.

Comment: Had a fun conversation when getting set up for campus WiFi. Him: "What is your MAC address?" Me: "What would you like it to be?"

Comment: Why isn't it the case any more?